# Identify the intersection between a Quadric and a plane

Tags: solution-verification, conic-sections, 3d, quadrics

I am considering a given quadric

$ r^T Q r + b^T r + c = 0 $

and its intersection with a given plane

$ n^T (r - r_0) = 0 $

and I want to identify the intersection curve between the two.

**My attempt:**

From the equation of the plane, one can find two mutually orthogonal unit vectors $u_1, u_2$ that are also orthogonal to $n$, and thus the plane can parameterised by

$ p = r_0 + x u_1 + y u_2  = r_0 + V u $

where $V = [u_1, u_2] $ and $ u = [x, y]^T $

Plugging this into the equation of the quadric

$ (r_0 + V u) ^T Q (r_0 + V u) + b^T (r_0 + V u) + c = 0 $

which becomes

$ u^T Q_1 u + b_1^T u + c_1 = 0 $

Now it is a matter of identifying the curve described by this quadratic equation.

The possible curves are:  Ellipse, Hyperbola, Parabola, Two intersecting lines, Two parallel lines, A single line, A single point, or the empty set.

I appreciate any additional input, or further details that I may have missed.

Comment: I would expand the parenthesis, and note that $(Vu)^T=u^TV^T$ Then the only thing that you need to classify the curves is the $V^TQV$ matrix.